# Where can I find Hiranyagarbha Samhita?

Tags: scripture, resource

I was looking out for sometime but couldn't find it.e-book, online text,book for sale or any format will be helpful.

Comment: I think it's one of the Pancharatra text.

Comment: Is this Samhita available then?

Comment: I don't find it. There are many Pancharatra text available on [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/pancaratra-agamas), however I don't find Hiranyagarbha Samhita at there.

Answer (score 1):

Did you found this book anywhere? I found few articles from that book while reading other books.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).